# How do I make my site always show the same URL in the address bar at all times

Tags: url, redirect

I have a primary domain (mydomain.com) and want to add a subdomain (sub.mydomain.com), but in the end I want the URL to point to another domain name (myotherdomainname.ca).

As well, I want to have the site stay on the "myotherdomainname.ca" at all times when within that subdomain. 
ex. myotherdomain.ca/page1 --> Address bar shows "myotherdomain.ca"

I'm not strong on coding, been many years, but can try and work my way through examples to get it to work (I hope).

Thanks in advance.

I've googles for this and researched a dozen sites, but I'm still lost.

Alas, I have no code to show as I wouldn't even know where to begin.

myotherdomain.ca/page1 --> Address bar shows "myotherdomain.ca"
myotherdomain.ca/pagex --> Address bar shows "myotherdomain.ca"

NOTE: Apologies if there's a thread on this already - I've searched here and other sites, but have not found one. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Building a single page application (SPA) might be a good choice if you're starting from scratch. With SPA, you mainly change the content of the page using JavaScript instead of link changes. Some of the better SPA frameworks include [Angular](https://angular.io/), [React](https://reactjs.org/) and [Vue](https://vuejs.org/).